# Building a list with some hierarchical elements

Tags: java, list, one-to-many, hierarchy

I have a SQL table describing books in the online library. it looks like this:

```
  create table if not exists BOOKS (
  BOOK_ID        char(36) default (UUID()) not null, 
  TITLE          varchar(255) not null, 
  URL            varchar(512), 
  PUBLISHED_ON   date, 
  ISBN           varchar(24), 
  ANNOTATION     text, 
  COMMENTARY     text, 
  RATING         tinyint, 
  SERIES_ID      char(36), 
  SERIES_VOL_NUM tinyint, 
  constraint BOOK_PK primary key (BOOK_ID),
  constraint FK_BOOKS_SERIES foreign key (SERIES_ID) references BOOKS (BOOK_ID)
);
```

Foreign key to itself needed as books might be linked to a series (like Harry Potter has 7 books and James Bond series has over 40). The hierarchy might be 2, 3 and very rare cases 4 level deep.

I have created Java class Book reflecting the information in the table and another class

```
public class Series extends Book {
    
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<Book> volumes;
    // setters and getters omitted
 }
```

When I am retrieving book info per given criteria, I am getting a plain list of all books and now I do need to build a list that will contain some hierarchy. I.e. I need to present it like following:

> ```
>  Book1
>  Book2
>  Series1
>    Volume 1 of S1
>    Volume 2 of S1
>       Part 1 of V2S1
>       Part 2 of V2S1
>    Volume 3 of S1
>  Book3
>  Book4
>  Series2
>    Volume1 of S2
>    Volume2 of S2
> ```

etc.
It is not a tree ( in that case I'd use recursion) and I am wrecking my brain on how to do it effectively. If someone can give me a hint, I will appreciate it.

Comment: are you trying to reformat a list of books into a list of books/series?

Comment: You got it right. I do need a list of books/series.